# How do I clone an Azure Managed Disk into a different subscription?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, disk, managed

Using Azure VMs and managed disks (using the ARM deployment model), I have recently run into the following problem I would like to solve: In order to get production data out from a managed disk for testing purposes, I would like to clone a production data disk from the "Production Subscription" into a managed disk in the "Development Subscription", where I can play around with the data in a safe way.

We are talking quite a lot of data (200 GB+), so that an actual "copying" process would take far too much time. I want to be able to automate things and provision new environments in - let's say, under half an hour.

Cloning a managed disk within a subscription (given it's in the same region) is very simple and fast, I just have to specify a `--source` to the `az disk create` command. This does not work across subscriptions obviously, at least because the logged in user/service principal for the development subscription does not have access to the production subscription resources.

What I have tried so far:

- Using `az disk grant-access` to retrieve an SAS URI for the managed disk; this thing is not accepted as a `--source` for `az disk create` though (it says VHD SAS links would work though...)

Any ideas?

Comment: well, grant access to the user?

Comment: Will have to try whether that works when the user in question is a service principal. Doubt it, as those belong to a subscription afaik.

Comment: I'm surprised the sas uri doesn't work across subscriptions - was the disk online when you tried running the cmd?  You can grant SPs permissions in multiple subs (at least in the same tenant, not sure about across tenant).  Another option would be to try a template deployment.

Comment: You could do it by PowerShell,  please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-managed-disks-overview) find `Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy`

Comment: Granting access to the subscription for the service principal, i.e. adding it to the roles of the subscription, was the key. It was too simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
$RG = "youresourcegroup"
$Location = "West US 2"
$StorageAccName = "yourstorage"
$SkuName = "Standard_LRS"
$Containername = "images"
$Destdiskname = “yorblob.vhd”
$SourceSASurl = "https://yoursaasurl"

Login-AzureRmAccount

New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $RG -Location $Location
New-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $StorageAccName -SkuName $SkuName -kind Storage -Location $Location 

$Storageacccountkey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $StorageAccName
$Storagectx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccName -StorageAccountKey $Storageacccountkey[0].Value

$Targetcontainer = New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $Containername -Context $storagectx -Permission Blob


$sourceSASurl = $mdiskURL.AccessSAS
$ops = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $SourceSASurl -DestBlob $Destdiskname -DestContainer $Containername -DestContext $Storagectx
Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState -Container $Containername -Blob $Destdiskname -Context $Storagectx -WaitForComplete
```

After this you will have a copy of managed disk in your subscription stored as a regular blob.

Be careful, you should obtain SAS URL from Production subscription, but in the script you should login to a Development subscription.

Next you can go to the Azure Portal and convert the blob to managed disk.

1. Go to Azure portal --> More Services --> Disks or directly browse this URL https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.ManagedDisk-ARM
2. Click +Add
3. Select source as storage blob
4. Select your vhd using source blob field.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I wrote to migrate all managed disks for each VM from one subscription to another. I hope this helps you.

```
# This script will get ALL VMs in a subscription and then migrate the disks 
if the VM has managed disks
# Created by Joey Brakefield -- @kfprugger & https://www.linkedin.com/in/joeybrakefield/

#set global variables
$sourceSubscriptionId='6a1b5e5e-df06-4608-a7a2-6984f7abacd8'
select-azurermsubscription -subscriptionid $sourceSubscriptionId
$vms = get-azurermvm
$targetSubscriptionId='929e0340-bf36-45a2-8347-47f86b4715de'


#looping logic for each of the VMs that have managed disks
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
select-azurermsubscription -subscriptionid $sourceSubscriptionId

$vmrg = get-azurermresourcegroup -name $vm.ResourceGroupName
$vmname = $vm.name

Write-Host = "Working with: " $vmname " in " $vmrg -foregroundcolor Green 
Write-Host ""

#This command will only target managed disks because unmanaged use the storage account locations rather than the /disks provider URIs

if (Get-AzureRmDisk | ? {$_.OwnerId -like "/subscriptions/"+$sourceSubscriptionId +"/resourceGroups/"+$vmrg.resourcegroupname+"/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/"+$vm.name})
{
#Sanity Check
#Read-host "Look correct? If not, CTRL-C to Break"
$manageddisk =  Get-AzureRmDisk | ? {$_.OwnerId -like "/subscriptions/"+$sourceSubscriptionId +"/resourceGroups/"+$vmrg.resourcegroupname+"/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/"+$vm.name}
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $targetSubscriptionId
#check to see if RG exists in the new CSP/Subscription 

Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $vmrg.resourcegroupname -ev notPresent -ea 0
write-host "Checking to see if"$vmrg.resourcegroupname"exists in subscriptionid"$targetSubscriptionId -foregroundcolor Cyan
Write-Host ""
if ($notPresent)
{
    new-azurermresourcegroup -name $vmrg.resourcegroupname -location $vmrg.location
    "Resource Group " + $vmrg.resourcegroupname + " has been created"
    } else {"Resource Group " + $vmrg.resourcegroupname +  " already exists"}
    # Move the disks after all checks are done
    foreach ($disk in $managedDisk){
        $managedDiskName = $disk.Name
        $targetResourceGroupName = $vmrg.resourcegroupname

        $diskConfig = New-AzureRmDiskConfig -SourceResourceId $disk.Id -Location $disk.Location -CreateOption Copy 

        New-AzureRmDisk -Disk $diskConfig -DiskName $Disk.Name -ResourceGroupName $targetResourceGroupName}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following commands in **Azure CLI** -

```
# Source storage account name
STORAGE1=sourcestorage

#Security key of the source storage account
STORAGEKEY1= SampleKey0qNzttE/EX3hHfcFIzkQQmqXklRU2Z2uANICw==

#Container containing the source VHD
CONTAINER1=sourcevhds

# Name of VHD to be copied (name only, not full url)
DISK=DiskToBeCopied.vhd

#Specify the above properties for target
STORAGE2=targetstorage
STORAGEKEY2= SampleKeyAb6FYP3EqFVEcN2cc5wO QHzXvdc7Gzh1qRt0FXKq6w==
CONTAINER2= targetvhds
```

After setting the above parameters, execute the following command in Azure CLI -

```
azure storage blob copy start --account-name $STORAGE1 --account-key $STORAGEKEY1 --source-container $CONTAINER1 --source-blob $Disk --dest-account-name $STORAGE2 --dest-account-key $STORAGEKEY2 --dest-container $CONTAINER2
```